# close low level Dialog when closed upper level Dialog

Tags: android

I have a button when clicked gives a spiner drop down Dialog. When I click the spiner gives me a AlertDailog.When I click on the ok I want to close both the dailogs and write the data obtained from the spiner data to a TextView?any help?

Comment: post code you have tried..

Comment: Pass the instance of spinner Dialog to Alert dialog and on click of OK close both the dialogs and show the text selected from spinner to textview

Comment: here is the code http://pastebin.ca/3232839

Comment: I solved this issue by adding a button to the custom layout and onclick even I called the dismiss() method.  Thank you.